# How to cache PageImpl with Spring Data Geode?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-gemfire, geode

When trying to cache a PageImpl response from a Spring Data JpaRepository using Spring Data Geode, it fails to cache the result with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer.fromData(MappingPdxSerializer.java:422) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxReaderImpl.basicGetObject(PdxReaderImpl.java:741) ~[geode-core-9.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxReaderImpl.getObject(PdxReaderImpl.java:682) ~[geode-core-9.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.geode.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readPdxSerializable(InternalDataSerializer.java:3054) ~[geode-core-9.1.1.jar:?]
```

It looks like the MappingPdxSerializer looks for a default constructor but doesn't find it for a PageImpl class.

Here is maven pom for the dependencies I have:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The JpaRepository I am using is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Long>
{
    @Override
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = { "Records" })
    <S extends Record> S save(S s);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "Records")
    Optional<Record> findById(Long id);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "Records", key = "#pageable.pageNumber + '.' + #pageable.pageSize + '.records'")
    Page<Record> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "Records")
    Record getOne(Long aLong);
}
```

The code used to invoke a repository paged result is:

```
int PAGE=0,PAGE_SIZE=100;
        Page<Record> recordPage;
        do {
            recordPage = recordRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(PAGE, PAGE_SIZE));
            log.info("Retrieved page: [{}]", recordPage);
        } while (recordPage.hasNext());
```

I feel like it maybe a possible bug with the MappingPdxSerializer, but I'm not 100% sure. Any help in resolving this issue would be awesome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you feel this is a possible bug with *Spring Data Geode's* (SDG) `o.s.d.g.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer`?

It is quite common, and even expected, that not all objects passed through SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` will have a default (i.e. public, no-arg) constructor.

When using such types in your application (e.g. like the SD `PageImpl` class) and an instance of that type is read from Apache Geode (e.g. `get(key)`), the object is de-serialized and reconstructed on the (Region) data access operation (providing Apache Geode's `read-serialized` configuration attribute is not set to **true**; which cause you other problems and not recommended in this case), then you need to register an [`EntityInstantiator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/convert/EntityInstantiator.html) that informs SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` how to instantiate the object, using an appropriate constructor.

The "appropriate" constructor is determined by the persistent entity's [`PreferredConstructor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/PreferredConstructor.html), which is evaluated during type evaluation by the SD Mapping Infrastructure, and can be specified with the [`@PersistenceContructor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/PersistenceConstructor.html) annotation, if necessary.  This is useful in cases where you are using 1 of SD's canned `EntityIntantiator` types, e.g. [`ReflectionEntityInstantiator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/convert/ReflectionEntityInstantiator.html), and your application domain type has more than 1 non-default constructor.

Therefore, you can register 1 or more `EntityInstantiator` objects per application domain object by type using the [`EntityIntantiatiors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/convert/EntityInstantiators.html) composite class, perhaps [with a "mapping"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/convert/EntityInstantiators.html#EntityInstantiators-java.util.Map-) between application domain object `Class` type (e.g. `Page`) and `EntityInstantiator`, and then [register](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/MappingPdxSerializer.html#setGemfireInstantiators-org.springframework.data.convert.EntityInstantiators-) the `EntityInstantiators` on  SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer`.

Of course, you need to make sure that custom configured `MappingPdxSerializer` gets used by Apache Geode...

```
@Configuration
class ApacheGeodeConfiration {

  @Bean
  MappingPdxSerializer pdxSerializer() {

    Map<Class<?>, EntityInstantiator> customInstantiators = new HashMap<>();

    customInstantiators.put(Page.class, new MyPageEntityInstantiator());
    customInstantiators.put...

    MappingPdxSerializer pdxSerializer = 
      MappingPdxSerializer.newMappingPdxSerializer();

    pdxSerializer.setGemfireInstantiators(
      new EntityInstantiators(customInstantiators));

    return pdxSerializer;
  }

  @Bean
  CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache(MappingPdxSerializer pdxSerializer) {

    CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new CacheFactoryBean();

    gemfireCache.setPdxSerializer(pdxSerializer);
    gemfireCache.set...

    return gemfireCache;
  }

  ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

-j